# Unwanted flat graph while drawing live gnuplot as command from c++ code, using popen() method

Tags: c++, debian, pipe, gnuplot, livegraph

I wanted to include in c++ code the graph updated live while more data is collected from pipe, this was using 'popen()' method. I wanted pure plot to draw data as they are calculated.
Here in example below I wanted 'y=2*x' function. But `gnuplot` draws only flat line presenting last point (constant y value for all x data). This flat line just changes 'height' after plot refreshing, because of changing input from pipe.

my code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
  {
  
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  fp =popen ("gnuplot-x11 -persist", "w");
  
  int i =0;
  unsigned char x_data[100000],
                y_data[100000];
  
  
  for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
    {
    
    x_data[i]=i;
    y_data[i]=2*i;
  
    printf("%0u\t %0u\n", x_data[i], y_data[i]);
    }
    printf("end of init\n");
    
  fprintf(fp, "plot '-'\n");
  for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
  {
    printf ("%0u\t %0u\n", x_data[i], y_data[i]); // to check x, y
    
    fprintf(fp,"set xrange[0:100]\n"); //fprintf(fp, "set xrange[0:%0u]\n", i);
    fprintf(fp, "set yrange[0:255]\n");
    fprintf(fp, "plot %0u, %0u", x_data[i], y_data[i]);
    fprintf(fp, " with points\n");
    fflush(fp);
   }
    
    pclose(fp);
    
    
  return 0;
  }
```

I tried to keep two variables, because when tested on textfile - `gnuplot` automatically takes 1st column as 'x' and second as 'y', but not in my code - it uses both variables as 'y' (two flat lines).
I tried to force `gnuplot` to use two variables in last fprintf command:

```
fprint(fp, "plot %0u, %0u"), x_data[i], y_data[i]);
fprint(fp, "**using 1:2** with points\n");
```

but `gnuplot` sends back 'unexpected or unrecognized token '
I also try to use '-' method but `gnuplot` sends 'Bad data on line 1 of file', even when I forced special characters '''
Another try was to use `fflush(fd);` outside of 'for (i)' loop, same result (flat graph).

This c++ is in Debian system on Raspberry pi 4. I use Geany for coding and there is no difference when I call 'gnuplot-x11', or simple 'gnuplot'.
I know there is a way to save data to file, even temporary - it works, but I want to check all possible solutions before I retreat.
Thanks for your support.

**EDIT**

thanks to suggested idea I changed the code. Data is sent directly after 'plot'. new part looks as follows:

```
  fprintf(fp, "plot '-' using 2:1 \t");
   for (i=0; i<=1000; i++)
   {
    fprintf(fp, "%0u, %0u\t", x_data[i], y_data[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "with points\n");
   }
```

And it works as I wanted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you checked `help inline data` how to send the data? First the `plot '-' u 1:2 w lines` command and then directly after just the data. Why do you have second plot command *in* the loop? `"plot %0u, %0u",`

Comment: Hi again, THX for fast response,
Answering question: in fact I left the first <code>plot '-' u 1:2  wl</code> just to show that it is not working, because second 'plot' worked somehow.

Comment: BUT -thanks to @theozh idea to check the  'help' again - I realized my error in syntax of function.
So improved it with following. 
1) divide the 'plot '-'... function and finish it -using \n - as last part in the loop, after sending x and y to gnuplot 
2) send data directly after plot '-' function 
Now it works much better - I can draw y=2*x and it's represented as I needed
Thanks again

Comment: If the problem is solved, please post your working code as answer (and you should accept your own answer). This will not let the question appear unanswered., according to the StackOverflow rule: No answers in comments.

Answer (score 0):

after improvements working code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <fcntl.h>
//#include <unistd.h>
//#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
  {
  
  FILE *fp = NULL;
  fp =popen ("gnuplot-x11 -persist", "w");
  
  int i =0;
  unsigned int x_data[100000],
               y_data[100000];
  
  for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
    {
    x_data[i]=i;
    y_data[i]=2*i;
  
    //printf("%0u\t %0u\n", x_data[i], y_data[i]); //to check data
    }
    printf("end of init\n");
    
  fprintf(fp, "set xrange[0:%0u]\n", i); 
  fprintf(fp, "set yrange[0:255]\n");  

  fprintf(fp, "plot '-' using 2:1 \t");
  
  for (i=0; i<=100; i++)
  {
    fprintf(fp, " %0u, %0u\t", x_data[i], y_data[i]);
    fprintf(fp, "with points\n");
  }
    
    fflush(fp);
    pclose(fp);
    
  return 0;
  }
```

The solution was to improve inline 'plot' syntax which starts before 'for' loop and finishes inside the loop.
Now it has only one 'plot' command for data and this is very last gnuplot command - after any 'set' instructions.

Comment: are you sure you want to write `with points\n` 100 times into your data? This should be in the plot command `plot  '-' using 2:1 with points\n`. And then just the datalines with `\n` as newline character.

Comment: @theoz, this idea even improved my code, because program earlier returned error, when gnuplot continued to read strange source of data. Now I just keep formatted data.
so the _for_ loop is only in one line `fprintf(fp, "%0u, %0u \n", x_data[i], y_data[i]);`